# slow down in SUSE linux enterprise server

Tags: linux, memory, performance, lag

I have run a mongodb process that uses most of the RAM (around 10 GB out of the total 11 GB). But immediately after I stop it, there is a huge slow down (even during the process but that is understandable). Even the clear command takes around 30 seconds to run. Is this a sign that I am killing the RAM? Is it due to something else? Or is this just expected behavior? I am willing to provide any additional details that may be required. I think that this could be due to mongodb but even after I close it, it still remains slow.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you write an interface with the db?  When you exit, is the memory being freed (check your system monitor) - or was the memory not deallocated in an interface with the db?  Just my initial thoughts, may not be fully relevant.

Comment: well the system monitoring tools such as iostat top free etc themselves take a long time to display their analysis. However, they do not reflect anything that shows there is a change. Thx